# Adding a Console User to WebSphere in jython

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

I need to add Administrative users to the WebSphere Console using a Jython script.  I tried to turn on the "Log command assistance commands" preference, but it did not log adding a user.  It did log other stuff though.

We setup alot of servers and are trying to script the entire setup process.

Cheers,
Konrad

Comment: any success? Please post your answer, I would be interested in this.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't done the administrative user, however, I have done a JAAS user. Following the script, it might give you enough hints on how to do it.

```python
def dbAuthenticationAlias():
   print 'Create JAAS - J2C Authentication Alias'

   #--------------------------------------------------------------
   # Check if JAAS - J2C Authentication Alias exists
   #--------------------------------------------------------------

   global dbuseralias

   # generate user alias
   dbuseralias = nodeName + '/' + dbuser

   # get context 
   sec = AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:%s/Security:/' % cellName)

   #Get all J2C Authentication Aliases (they are separated by \n
   j2c = AdminConfig.list('JAASAuthData',sec)

   found = 0
   if len(j2c) > 0 :
      for j2cUserId in j2c.splitlines():
         if AdminConfig.showAttribute(j2cUserId,"alias") == dbuseralias:
            found = 1

   #--------------------------------------------------------------
   # Create a JAAS - J2C Authentication Alias
   #--------------------------------------------------------------
   if found == 0 :
      print 'user not found, creating'

      # create structure for J2C Authentication Alias
      jaasAttrs = [['alias', dbuseralias],['userId', dbuser],['password',dbpassword]]  

      #create J2C Authentication Alias
      AdminConfig.create('JAASAuthData', sec, jaasAttrs)

      print 'user %s created' % dbuseralias

      #saving
      adminConfigSave()
   else:
      print 'user found'
```

I had problems so far, finding, where a specif setting is to be made. So I used following commands within wsadmin tool to retrieve the current configuration.

```python
sec = AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:%s/Security:/' % cellName)
#shows all attributes for the config element given by an ID 
print AdminConfig.show(sec) 
#shows all attributes and expands the attributes where necessary 
print AdminConfig.showall(sec)
```

Instead of retrieving the security settings you can also retrieve the server settings and subsequently moving deeper in the configuration tree.

```python
srv = AdminConfig.getid('/Node:%s/Server:%s/' % (node,server)) 
#get the process definition from server config 
prcDef = AdminConfig.list('ProcessDef',srv) 
#get JVM config from process definition 
jvm= AdminConfig.list('JavaVirtualMachine',prcDef)
```